# How to reset count in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list with four items. Each item have a counter. When we click on the item, the count will increase. I want to reset the counter value by zero except the clicking item. This is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/30662/).

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

var jsonInfo = {"count":[{"name":"one",count:0} ,{"name":"two",count:0},{"name":"three",count:0} ,{"name":"four",count:0}]}

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.data =jsonInfo;

  $scope.count = function (inc) {
    inc.count =  inc.count + 1
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this. Loop over all items and check if the clicked item is the current one: increment and for others set to 0.

**[Try DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6qoLq2co/4/)**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

var jsonInfo = {"count":[{"name":"one",count:0} ,{"name":"two",count:0},{"name":"three",count:0} ,{"name":"four",count:0}]}

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.data =jsonInfo;

  $scope.count = function (inc) {
     jsonInfo.count.forEach((item) => {
        item.count = item.name === inc.name? inc.count + 1 : 0; 
     });
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.data =jsonInfo;

  $scope.count = function (inc) {

  for(i=0; i<jsonInfo.count.length; i++){
      if(jsonInfo.count[i].name != inc.name){
      jsonInfo.count[i].count = 0;
      }
  }
    inc.count =  inc.count + 1
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function resetOherCount(inc) {

    jsonInfo.count.map(function(oneEle) {
        if (oneEle.name != inc.name) {
            oneEle.count = 0
        }
        return oneEle;
    });
}

$scope.count = function (inc) {

    resetOherCount(inc);
    inc.count = inc.count + 1
};
```